# Reading TidTCPServer incoming data until disconnect

Tags: indy10

I'm trying to migrate from Delphi's TTCPserver to Indy's TidTCPServer (Delphi XE10.2), but I cannot figure out how read the incoming data in the Execute, all examples I've found is using readln which needs a "ETX" char. And I haven't found anyway to get the received no of bytes or any length.

So how do I read the full package? 
I imagined something like; *read bytes until "disconnect"*

I tried this below (not at the same time though), I do not get any packages or bytes except from if I use a telnet client and type characters from the keyboard - that'll give me data byte by byte. But a package from the "3rd party client" never appears. I see the client connect and disconnect again.

```
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
    Port          : Integer;
    PeerPort      : Integer;
    PeerIP        : string;
    msgFromClient : string;
    msgToClient   : string;
    buf : TidBytes;
    l :integer;
    ABufStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
// this doesn't return anything
    ABufStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
     //       AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ABufStream, -1, True);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferToStream(ABufStream, -1);
      ABufStream.Position := 0;
      ABufStream.WriteBuffer(buf, ABufStream.Size);
      msgFromClient := format('received %d bytes',[ABufStream.Size]);
    finally
       ABufStream.Free;
    end;

// this doesn't return anything neither
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(buf, -1, False);
    l := length(buf);
    if l > 0 then
      Display('CLIENT', '(Bytes =' + IntToStr(l));
end;
```

The data I receive en an "array of bytes" where there are no ETX (or end of package) the way it works is like this

1. A Client connects (starts a tcp session)
2. The Client sends the package of N bytes
3. The Client disconnects (end of TCP session)

The package contains a header and a length of the data part in the first 8 bytes.

My old code from TTCPServer looks like this:

```
procedure TDispatchScanThread.TCPServerOnAccept(Sender: TObject; ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  s: ShortString;
  l: integer;
  Buf: TDataBuf; // TDataBuf = array[0..MAX_DATAPACKET] of byte;
  ADispatchPacket: TDispatchPacket;
  AQueuedStatus : Boolean;

begin
  try
    LogQueue.AddToLog(format('TCPServer receiving (onAccept)',[]), llvVerbose);
    ZeroMemory(@Buf, MAX_DATAPACKET);
    l := ClientSocket.PeekBuf(Buf, 8);
    if (l <> SOCKET_ERROR) and (l = 8) then
    begin
      s := '0000';       // check if IVD version header is valid for us
      Move(Buf[0], s[1], 4);
      if not(s = sHeaderID) then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet HeaderID %s', [s]);

      s := '0000';       // Fetch data package length
      Move(Buf[4], s[1], 4);
      l := StrToInt(s);
      ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Buf[0], l + HEADER_SIZE);       // total length is header + data

      // Create the dispatch packet object, move the data to the buffer and queue it.
      ADispatchPacket := TDispatchPacket.Create;
      ADispatchPacket.ReplyTime := MilliSecondOfTheDay(UTCNow);
      ADispatchPacket.DataBuf := Buf; // the setter copies the buffer contens

      AQueuedStatus := CommandQueue.Enqueue(TOmniMessage.Create(ord(itmDispatchPackage), ADispatchPacket));
      LogQueue.AddToLog(Format('Received package: %d bytes, incoming package was queued = [%s]',[l + HEADER_SIZE, booltostr(AQueuedStatus, True)]), llvVerbose);
    end else
        begin
          LogQueue.AddError(format('TCPServer socket error: %d',[l]));
        end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      LogQueue.AddError(format('TcpServerAccept Error: %s',[E.Message]));
      FreeAndNil(ADispatchPacket);
    end;
  end; // except
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages you are receiving have a structure to them - a 4-byte message ID, followed by a 4-byte ASCII string specifying the message data length, followed by the actual message data.

Your `TTCPServer` code is following that structure, but your `TIdTCPServer` code is not (not even close!).  If anything, Indy makes this kind of job easy, because Indy's `TIdIOHandler` class has many methods available for reading all kinds of data formats, whereas `TTCPServer` does not offer anything to help you at all, you have to read and parse everything manually.

In this case, you could use the `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes()` methods, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
  l: integer;
  Buf: TDataBuf; // TDataBuf = array[0..MAX_DATAPACKET] of byte;
  ADispatchPacket: TDispatchPacket;
  AQueuedStatus : Boolean;
  IdBuf: TIdBytes;
begin
  LogQueue.AddToLog(format('TCPServer receiving (onExecute)',[]), llvVerbose);
  ZeroMemory(@Buf, MAX_DATAPACKET);

  // check if IVD version header is valid for us
  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(4);
  if s <> sHeaderID then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet HeaderID %s', [s]);
  Move(ShortString(s)[1], Buf[0], 4);

  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(4);
  l := StrToInt(s);
  Move(ShortString(s)[1], Buf[4], 4);

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(IdBuf, l);
  Move(PByte(IdBuf)^, Buf[8], l);

  // Create the dispatch packet object, move the data to the buffer and queue it.
  ADispatchPacket := TDispatchPacket.Create;
  try
    ADispatchPacket.ReplyTime := MilliSecondOfTheDay(UTCNow);
    ADispatchPacket.DataBuf := Buf; // the setter copies the buffer contens

    AQueuedStatus := CommandQueue.Enqueue(TOmniMessage.Create(ord(itmDispatchPackage), ADispatchPacket));
  except
    ADispatchPacket.Free;
    raise;
  end;

  LogQueue.AddToLog(Format('Received package: %d bytes, incoming package was queued = [%s]',[l + HEADER_SIZE, booltostr(AQueuedStatus, True)]), llvVerbose);

  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  LogQueue.AddError(format('TcpServer Error: %s',[AException.Message]));
end;
```

Or, you could use the `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` method, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: ShortString;
  l: integer;
  Buf: TDataBuf; // TDataBuf = array[0..MAX_DATAPACKET] of byte;
  ADispatchPacket: TDispatchPacket;
  AQueuedStatus : Boolean;
  ABufStream : TIdMemoryBufferStream;
begin
  LogQueue.AddToLog(format('TCPServer receiving (onExecute)',[]), llvVerbose);
  ZeroMemory(@Buf, MAX_DATAPACKET);

  ABufStream := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(@Buf, SizeOf(Buf));
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ABufStream, 8, False);

    // check if IVD version header is valid for us
    s := '0000';       // check if IVD version header is valid for us
    Move(Buf[0], s[1], 4);
    if s <> sHeaderID then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet HeaderID %s', [s]);

    s := '0000';       // Fetch data package length
    Move(Buf[4], s[1], 4);
    l := StrToInt(s);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ABufStream, l, False);

    // Create the dispatch packet object, move the data to the buffer and queue it.
    ADispatchPacket := TDispatchPacket.Create;
    try
      ADispatchPacket.ReplyTime := MilliSecondOfTheDay(UTCNow);
      ADispatchPacket.DataBuf := Buf; // the setter copies the buffer contens

      AQueuedStatus := CommandQueue.Enqueue(TOmniMessage.Create(ord(itmDispatchPackage), ADispatchPacket));
    except
      ADispatchPacket.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    ABufStream.Free;
  end;

  LogQueue.AddToLog(Format('Received package: %d bytes, incoming package was queued = [%s]',[l + HEADER_SIZE, booltostr(AQueuedStatus, True)]), llvVerbose);

  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  LogQueue.AddError(format('TcpServer Error: %s',[AException.Message]));
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: ShortString;
  l: integer;
  Buf: TDataBuf; // TDataBuf = array[0..MAX_DATAPACKET] of byte;
  ADispatchPacket: TDispatchPacket;
  AQueuedStatus : Boolean;
  ABufStream : TIdMemoryBufferStream;
begin
  LogQueue.AddToLog(format('TCPServer receiving (onExecute)',[]), llvVerbose);
  ZeroMemory(@Buf, MAX_DATAPACKET);

  ABufStream := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(@Buf, SizeOf(Buf));
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ABufStream, -1, True);

    if ABufStream.Size < 8 then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet Header size %d', [ABufStream.Size]);

    // check if IVD version header is valid for us
    s := '0000';       // check if IVD version header is valid for us
    Move(Buf[0], s[1], 4);
    if s <> sHeaderID then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet HeaderID %s', [s]);

    s := '0000';       // Fetch data package length
    Move(Buf[4], s[1], 4);
    l := StrToInt(s);

    if ABufStream.Size < (l + HEADER_SIZE) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dispatch packet size %d, expected %d', [ABufStream.Size, l + HEADER_SIZE]);

    // Create the dispatch packet object, move the data to the buffer and queue it.
    ADispatchPacket := TDispatchPacket.Create;
    try
      ADispatchPacket.ReplyTime := MilliSecondOfTheDay(UTCNow);
      ADispatchPacket.DataBuf := Buf; // the setter copies the buffer contens

      AQueuedStatus := CommandQueue.Enqueue(TOmniMessage.Create(ord(itmDispatchPackage), ADispatchPacket));
    except
      ADispatchPacket.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    ABufStream.Free;
  end;

  LogQueue.AddToLog(Format('Received package: %d bytes, incoming package was queued = [%s]',[l + HEADER_SIZE, booltostr(AQueuedStatus, True)]), llvVerbose);
end;

procedure TForm2.IdTCPServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  LogQueue.AddError(format('TcpServer Error: %s',[AException.Message]));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy, 

I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my question, I wasn't trying to show a fully migrated procedure - I was only trying to receive something for a start.

I received nothing, but I found the cause - 

I used an example project I found and had this in the OnConnect

    msgToClient := 'Welcome ' + typeClient + ' ' + 'Client :)';
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn( msgToClient );


That is of course not accepted (not protocol) by the client and it disconnects and causes an #10053 exception.

Once removed I started to see the incomming data.

Comment: ran out of characters in comment, anyways - it's seems like a simple task to migrate to Indy and get rid of TTCPServer and TTCPClient :)